# Get Cart Subtotal including tax

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-1, quote, totals

I'm trying to get the subtotal of my cart in a variable. However, I need the subtotal including tax and at the moment it gives me the subtotal without the tax. This is my code:

```
 var second_number = <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I know you can do it by iterating the items:

```
<?php
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();
    $subtotalInclTax = 0;
    foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
        $subtotalInclTax += $item->getRowTotalInclTax();
    }
    Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($subtotalInclTax);
?>
```

Also if you have set Display Subtotal to Including Tax in the config you can do:

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to get the grand total, **but including shipping cost and discounts**, is:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getData('grand_total');
```

Or:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this includes shipping costs so it might not be what the OP needed.

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort You are right, this method gets the total including shipping and other costs

Comment: @AndresRojasOrozco I have to give free shipping order over and 1000 and zipcode between 600001 to 600010, i am using webshop matrix rate for shipping method, in this case, shopping cart pricing rule not working free shipping, so i have to plan for do custom PHP code for giving free shipping, My condition how can i give condition like subtotal is equal or greated than 1000 and zipcode 600001 and 600010 in /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your magento settings for "Display Subtotal" is "Including Tax". You can find by logging into magento admin and then:

- Click System menu
- Click Tax under SALES section at left menu
- There will be "Display Subtotal" under "Shopping Cart Display Settings"

Then the following code will show subtotal including tax:

`<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); ?>;`